# g++ no longer finding standard libraries OSX 10.6.8

Tags: c++, shell, command-line

no solutions I found on the internet have worked so far.

I am running OSX 10.6.8. I had previously been using the gnu compiler for C/C++ fine. I switched to XCode and have no problem with that but I would like to use the command line. However, after wiping my computer and restoring from a backup I was getting the error bash: g++ command not found.

First, I figured my $PATH got a bit wonky, so I tried to add in the correct path to the Path variable and now it recognizes g++ and tries to compile. But, I get this error now:

```
hello.cpp:3:20: error: iostream: No such file or directory
hello.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
hello.cpp:8: error: ‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

Here is the Hello World! code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
std::cout << "Hello World!";
return 0;
}
```

Solutions that have been posted online have mainly been problems with namespaces and #include statements but I do not believe this to be the error at this time.

when I type "which g++" into Terminal I get: /Developer/usr/bin/g++
and when I type g++ -v I get:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5666.3~6/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
```

4.2.1 is an older version so if there is one thing I could change it would be switching to 4.7.2 which I found in usr/local/Cellar/gcc. I am not sure what Cellar is perhaps that comes from when I tried using homebrew to install gcc as I found on some other forum.

Thanks in advance, this is beyond my ken.

Comment: "I had previously been using the gnu compiler for C/C++ fine. I switched to Xcode" - here you screwed up. Go back to the command line, really. Xcode is crap. (Oh, and +1 for compensating the time you wasted on this problem introduced by Xcode's programming antipatterns.)

Answer (score 0):

When you installed XCode, you simply forgot to check that little checkbox that says "install Unix command line utilities." When you do that, you'll get a fully working GCC installed in /usr/. The one installed in /Developer/ is not for command-line use. It's only for the XCode graphical IDE.

Comment: alright so I should be reinstalling Xcode then and checking that box? My version of Xcode is 3.2.6 and I had checked Apple's Developer site and they didn't seem to have the download for anything before 4. I will check the cd though.

Comment: @DavidH The latest XCode for OS X 10.6 is 3.2.6 (xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg). So you already have the latest version. Later versions of XCode are only for OS X 10.7 and up. I don't think you need to reinstall completely though. Maybe launching the installer again will simply allow you to modify the existing installation. Try that and simply install the Unix tools.